# send ASIFormDataRequest request

Tags: iphone, mysql, ipad, asiformdatarequest

I'm trying to send data from iPhone to php file to insert some data in mySql

in iPhone I wrote the following code:

```
-(IBAction) SendToServer{

NSString *phpUrl = @"http://mamdouhsaleh.com/myFolder/RegisteredPersons.php";

NSString *dbName = @"my_dbName";
NSString *localHost = @"localhost";
NSString *dbUser = @"my_userName";
NSString *dbPwd = @"my_password";

NSString *PersonName2 = personName.text;
NSString *CourseTitle2 = courseTitle.text;
NSString *MobileNo2 = mobileNo.text;
NSString *Email2 = email.text;


NSURL *link = [NSURL URLWithString:[phpUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:link];

[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setPostValue:dbName forKey:@"dbName"];
[request setPostValue:localHost forKey:@"localHost"];
[request setPostValue:dbUser forKey:@"dbUser"];
[request setPostValue:dbPwd forKey:@"dbPwd"];
[request setPostValue:@"" forKey:@"submit"];

[request setPostValue:PersonName2 forKey:@"PersonName"];
[request setPostValue:CourseTitle2 forKey:@"CourseTitle"];
[request setPostValue:MobileNo2 forKey:@"MobileNo"];
[request setPostValue:Email2 forKey:@"Email"];

[request setTimeOutSeconds:120];
[request setDelegate:self];
NSError *error = [request error];
[request startAsynchronous];

NSDictionary *questions = nil;
if (!error) {
    NSData *response = [request responseData];
    NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    questions = [json objectFromJSONString];
    NSLog(@"Data: %@", questions);

}
}
```

and im RegisteredPersons.php I wrote:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$dbName = $_POST['dbName'];
$localHost = $_POST['localHost'];
$dbUser = $_POST['dbUser'];
$dbPwd = $_POST['dbPwd'];

$con = mysql_connect($localHost,$dbUser,$dbPwd);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($dbName);

mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET UTF8');
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8; ");

$myPageId = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(ID) FROM RegisteredPersons");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($myPageId);

$personId = $row[0]++;
$PersonName = $_POST['PersonName']; 
$CourseTitle = $_POST['CourseTitle'];
$MobileNo = $_POST['MobileNo']; 
$Email = $_POST['Email']; 

mysql_query("INSERT INTO RegisteredPersons VALUES (". $personId . ", '" . $PersonName . "', '" . $CourseTitle . "', " . $MobileNo . ", '" . $Email . "')");


mysql_close();

}

?>
```

but the insertion doesn't happen in the RegisteredPersons table. What is the wrong in my code?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: To start I see one big thing that is wrong. You are starting an asynchronous request and trying to get the data from it before it finishes. For now you can change that to a synchronous request because for all you know you are getting an error before it even starts your php code. When you get that worked out I would start echoing out results from your php to see what its doing. I find it better to debug each piece separately and doing manual queries on your php page by just making the parameters GET and building out the URL

Comment: I changed to synchronous, and I tested my php really by echos and prints are all ok, but I can't find the error that prevent the insertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by Replacing 
     $personId = $row[0]++;
by 
     $personId = $row[0]+1;